# On JQuery focusout, determine if new focus is a child element or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I have a dropdown list of sorts that's attached to an input field. I only want to close the dropdown if the new focus on `focusout` is not a child.

```
<div class="input">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="results">
        <div class="result">someresult</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a `focusin` and `focusout` event handler attached to the `div` of class `input`. The `<input>` itself gains focus when clicked. When I click on a dropdown item (class `result`) `<input>` loses focus which triggers the `focusout` event. If I click elsewhere on the page, the `focusout` event is also fired.

I want to be able to tell if the new focused element is a child of `<div class="input">` or not, if not, then I will hide the dropdown, otherwise I will do nothing on this `focusout` and handle the click event on the result separately.

Note: `relatedTarget` doesn't seem to exist in Chrome or Firefox for the `focusout` event, which is the solution I've seen multiple times on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `click` event and check the `toElement` of the event to see which element was clicked.

In order to find clicks outside the `.input` container I added a listener to the click on the `document`.

Check the example here:

```js
$('.input').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  if ($(event.toElement).hasClass('text-input')) {
    console.log('input clicked');
  } else {
    console.log('clicked inside the `.input` container, outside the input field');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('document clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="text-input">
    <div class="results">
        <div class="result">someresult</div>
    </div>
</div>
```